# Не работает звук под root в xubuntu

Tags: linux, xubuntu, pulseaudio

Я пытаюсь включить звук под root в xubuntu.
Прежде всего запустил pulseaudio

```
pulseaudio -D
```

В pavucontrol появилось приложение (Mozzila Firefox). Звук с него попадает в pulseaudio. Индикатор звука скачет, звук идёт. Но ни во встроеных колонках ноутбука, ни через выход звука нет.
Что можно сделать?

Comment: вариант снести пульсу к чертям не рассматривается? или свежий огнелис к ней в бубунте гвоздями прибит?

Comment: @Fat-Zer нет не прибит, кроме pulseaudio нужно что-то удалять?

Comment: скорей всего нет, может только какие-то свои зависимости подтянет — обычно он относительно безболезненно убирается... но вот по поводу огнелиса посмотри внимательней — с некоторых пор апстрим решил собирать его без alsa... не знаю точно, сделели ли по этому поводу что-нибудь в бубунте или нет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer нет, звука нет и в VLC Player. Что еще можно попробывать?

Comment: в vlc достаточно будет в настройках переключиться на alsa, а с огнелисом, если нет, то скорей всего придётся пересобирать, но без особых навыков в этот омут бросаться не рекомендую... честно сказать, я не досконально знаю, как пульса работает, но вроде бы она открывает устройства вывода в монопольном режиме и не пускает других , так что два демона одновременно не должны были бы иметь возможность работать... так что, на сколько я понимаю, придётся убить пользовательского демона... ЗЫ: как бы то ни было, желание выводить звук от root'а довольно странное...

Comment: воспроизведение звука — это явно не административная задача. используйте привилегированную учётную запись **только** для выполнения задач по администрированию системы. // p.s. встроенный миелофон подсказывает, что вам, возможно, требуется mpd (music play daemon) из одноимённого пакета.

Comment: у меня была похожая проблема, я переключился во вкладку "конфигурация" в pavucontrol и выбрал там профиль "аналоговый стерео дуплекс". по умолчанию стоял другой профиль, по этому звука и не было.

Comment: создал нового пользователя, без root прав. Все заработало без настроек. Возьму как нибудь бутылку коньяка, и буду разбираться почему под root`om так нельзя. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Так а чё под обычным юзером не сидится-то, если под ним всё работает?